# TFS Backup Restore BackupSettings file missing issue

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS server 2018 Update 1. I have used it long time and it works well. Now I tried to restore the backup through TFS its shows that `BackupSettings.xml` file is missing. But In my backup folder `BackupSets.xml` file.

Old days `BackupSettings.xml` is created inside the backup folder. Now its replace with this `BackupSets.xml` file.

`BackupSets.xml` file is not recognized from the TFS server. I tried to rename the file but not working. If you have an idea for this issue please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BackupSettings.xml` file is not replaced with `BackupSets.xml` file, they are two different files, and they are supposed to exist together in the backup folder.

You can go to **Administration Console** -- **Logs** to check the backup logs to see whether there is any error. And go to **Scheduled Backups** to take another full backup.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have these logs. no errors. I will try to get manual backup.

Comment: Yes sure! Thanks